# Pause and wait for input in C# without Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#

How would I wait for input in C# using a method other than `Console.ReadKey()`? I don't need the input, I just need a pause. `Console.Readkey()`works fine, but it shows what you pressed. For example, the code below would work fine, but shows the key you pressed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Example
    {

    class Program
    {
        static void Wait()
        {
            Console.Write("\nPress Any Key To Continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //some code
            Wait();
            //some other code
            Wait();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply make it “Press space to continue” and check for this key instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For example, the code below would work fine, but shows the key you
>   pressed.

To solve this problem, use the ***intercept*** parameter:

```
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> *intercept* (System.Boolean)
>
> Determines whether to display the pressed key in the console
>   window. **true** to not display the pressed key; otherwise, **false**.

Answer (score -1):

u can use thread.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine("This is a demo!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this wait until the user has pressed a key as asked?